# Get the difference of the first 5 natural numbers in C

Tags: c

Whenever I try this the result is always like this: 1-2-3-4-5=-15 (I used `sum = sum-i`) but the answer should be `-13`.

I' use the method `sum = sum - i` and the answer is `-15` but it should be `-13`. I also tried `sum -= i` but same result.

Current code:

```
    printf("Input smallest number: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Input highest number: ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    for (disp = 0; i <= j; i++) {
        disp = disp - i;
        printf("%d ", i);
        if (i < j) {
            printf(" - ");
        } 
    }
    printf(" = %d", disp);
```

Comment: If you show your code, maybe we can explain what is bad in it... But if you do not, we just cannot help you :-(

Comment: Avoid writing code in comments but *edit* your question with it (I have done it for you this time...). Code in comment is really hard to read.

Comment: hint: your code calculates `0 -i -(i+1) … -(j-1) -j`

Comment: You should debug your algo with a piece of paper and a pencil. Never forget that it is the simplest way to initially look at what an algorithm does... You would immediately see that you actually do : 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5  which **is** 15

Answer (score 4):

The issue with your approach is that it initializes the `disp` to zero and afterwards subtracts the integers of range smallest to highest. In your example this results in `0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 = -15`. What you intuitively want is to initialize `disp` to the smallest integer and then subtract the integers of range smallest+1 to highest. This may look like this:

```c
int min;
int max;
printf("Input smallest number: ");
scanf("%d", &min);
printf("Input highest number: ");
scanf("%d", &max);
printf("%d", min);
int disp = min;
for (int i = min + 1; i <= max; i++) {
    disp -= i;
    printf(" - %d", i);
}
printf(" = %d\n", disp);
```

Be aware that you have to explore the edge cases like:

1. What if the user input is not a number?
2. What output do you expect from `min = max`?
3. How do you handle/prevent the user inputting `min > max`?

Answer (score 3):

> You should debug your algo with a piece of paper and a pencil. Never forget that it is the simplest way to initially look at what an algorithm does... You would immediately see that you actually do : 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 which is -15

–
Serge Ballesta